# Why does the result of Stern-Gerlach experiment SEMI-discrete?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, experimental-physics, quantum-spin

The pattern of Stern-Gerlach experiment on detector is not a continuous one but has two disjoint parts. But each of this two parts isn't such narrow that could be considered as a single values: $\frac{h}{2}$ and $-\frac{h}{2}$. compare with atomic radiation spectrum of elements, which have very narrow lines. What cause this thickness? Is this bacause silver atoms of the beam in the experiment have something like Newtonian rotation which disorder the experiment or any other explanation?

Comment: Maybe the original beam of atoms is not sufficiently narrow? The point is that each atom will be measured to have been deflected along one of two angles, but if different atoms start at different heights then they'll end up in different places. Maybe Heisenberg uncertainty must factor into where the atoms initially are and are going. Or, if different atoms experience the magnetic field for different lengths of time, their deflections will be different. Etc... now if all of that is accounted for and there's still excess width at the detectors, that's a question to be answered